# Babel not returning languages?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-babel

I'm trying to use [Babel 2.6.0](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/) to [get the "official" language(s)](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/api/languages.html) by territory but it returns nothing.

[image]

As seen [here](https://github.com/python-babel/babel/blob/master/tests/test_languages.py), it should take a two letter territory code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The USA [does not have an official language](https://www.cnn.com/2018/05/20/us/english-us-official-language-trnd/index.html). You can request the *de facto* language by setting the namesake flag:

```
get_official_languages("US",de_facto=True)
#('en',)
```